# Angular 8 Routing

Tags: angular

I'm using a metronic template for my project as most of things required are already present in the template, but while login it passes every valid email ID to next page when I change the API URL. So, I tried to change the code so it can function as per the requirement but the things is after validating the email ID, it's not taking me to next page. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

The template follows the this approach for routing:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
```

I tried it as:

```
this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
```

login.component.ts

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initLoginForm();

    // redirect back to the returnUrl before login
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.returnUrl = params['returnUrl'] || '/';
    });
   }

   submit() {
       this.auth.login(authData.email, authData.password)
       .subscribe((res) => {
         if(res.code === 200){
            localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token)
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl); // Main page
         }else{this.authNoticeService.setNotice(this.translate.instant('AUTH.VALIDATION.INVALID_LOGIN'), 'danger');}
       })
     }
```

The desired output should take it to the dashboard on providing the valid email ID and give error for wrong email ID. While it's not moving to next page which is dashboard on submit the button and on valid email (actual).

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe or take it in snapshot:

```
this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
```

To make it works when you redirect to login, don't forget to give the param

```
// e.g. we are in /list page 
this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: '/list' } });
```